# How can I get twitter's tweet button Response after successful tweet using Javascript and PHP API and also want to get total count of tweet for a url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter, jquery-events

I want to integrate Twitter custom share button in Wordpress Website. I am looking for twitter's tweet response after successful tweet using Javascript or PHP. I also want to get tweet count for a URL. I have tried but can't get anything.

I have tried this Javascript API of twitter, but nothing works.
Please help,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){ 
    window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));  
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind(
            'tweet',
            function (event) {
            alert("Tweeted");
            }
        );

    });     
});
```

Comment: There's no support for either of these features in the Twitter API or in the Twitter for Websites widgets. You will need to do a Twitter search to count the URL shares, and you will need to use the Twitter API to check whether a Tweet was posted after the Tweet JS event is completed.

Comment: I have tried all the ways but i am not getting anythings.

Comment: Can you show the code you have for accessing the Twitter Search API?

Comment: Yes, I have seen but getting nothing.

Comment: I’m not seeing any code here related to search? I think it would be helpful if you could clarify the question and what specifically you have been trying.